# Ho can I get these images to appear in random spots on the page?

Tags: javascript, css, image, random, position

I am creating a collage app that has an dogAPI.  When the breed is selected a dog image will appear.  I want the image to appear in a random spot on the page but ideally not over the text and dropdown menu.  This is what I have tried and here is my codepen.  This is an app so it needs to also be responsive.

```
    //Get a random number
let getRandomNum = (num) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(num));
}

//show image in a random location
let moveImg = () => {
    let dogImgs = document.querySelector('.dogPic')
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let h = window.innerHeight;
    dogImgs.style.top = getRandomNum(w) + "px";
    dogImgs.style.left = getRandomNum(h) + "px";
};
```

https://codepen.io/drxl/pen/VwbQZyK

Comment: Seems like you need min/max for your random number function. Or use a "container" element where your images will be placed.

Comment: I think you never invoked `moveImg()`

Comment: If you want to randomize position of newly added element, you would need more specific query selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `moveImg` function is flawed - it uses `querySelector` which will only select the first element. It should ideally accept an image as a parameter.

We can declare it like so:

```js
let moveImg = (dogImgs) => {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let h = window.innerHeight;
    dogImgs.style.top = getRandomNum(w) + "px";
    dogImgs.style.left = getRandomNum(h) + "px";
};
```

Then, in your `createImgs` function, simply pass the constructed image as a parameter to `moveImg`.

```js
// fetches dog breed list/shows error if applicable
async function start() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
        const data = await response.json()
        breedList(data.message)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("There was a problem fetching the breed list.")
        alert("There was a problem fetching the breed list.")
    }
}


//load breed list in dropdown menu
start()
function breedList(dogList) {
    document.getElementById("breeds").innerHTML = `
    <select onchange="loadByBreed(this.value)">
        <option>Choose a dog breed</option>
        ${Object.keys(dogList).map(function (breed) {
        return `<option>${breed}</option>`
    }).join('')}
    </select>
    `
}

//load images
async function loadByBreed(breed) {
    if (breed != "Choose a dog breed") {
        const response = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images`)
        const data = await response.json()
        createImgs(data.message)
    }
}

//show randomized images
function createImgs(images) {
    let imageContainer = $(".slideshow");
    let dogImgs = $('<img>');
    dogImgs.attr("src", images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]);
    dogImgs.addClass("dogPic")
    imageContainer.append(dogImgs);
    moveImg(dogImgs[0]);
}

//deletes pic if dbl tapped
$(document).on('dblclick', ".dogPic", function () {
    $(this).remove();
})

//resets select menu when image has loaded
$("#breeds").on("change", "select", function () {
    const value = this.value;
    console.log(value);
    let select = this

    setTimeout(function () {
        select.selectedIndex = 0;
    }, 800)
});

//Get a random number
let getRandomNum = (num) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(num));
}


let moveImg = (dogImgs) => {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let h = window.innerHeight;
    dogImgs.style.top = getRandomNum(w) + "px";
    dogImgs.style.left = getRandomNum(h) + "px";
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(26, 43, 38);
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
}


select {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.main-container  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


.slideshow {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}



img {
    max-width: 40%;
    margin-top: 25rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

.top_link_position {
    display: block;
  position: fixed;
    bottom: 4%;
    right: 3%;
    z-index: 600;
  }
  
  
  .top_btn {
      border: 1.5px solid white;
      background: black;
      padding: .5rem .5rem;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bolder;
      text-transform: uppercase;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .header {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
    select {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Dog Collage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Title and menu-->
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Dog Collage!</h1>
        <p>Select a dog and create your collage!</p>
        <p>Double-tap to remove an image.</p>
        <div id="breeds"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow" id="imgs">
</div>    

<!-- Modal
<div id="my-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="pokemonModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"  aria-labelledby="pokemonModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="modal-close" id=".modal-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -->

<!--Top of Page Button-->
<div  class="top_link_position">
    <a  class="back-to-top" href="#page_top" title="Top">
    <button class="top_btn"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-2x"></i></span></button>
    </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice it worked!, I am kind of a noob at JS so if you don't mind,  how do you know when to use a parameter (moveImg function) and then how did you know to pass the constructed image as a paramter?

Comment: @NamelessDude21 No worries :) Glad to help.

Comment: @NamelessDude21 *"how do you know when to use a parameter (moveImg function)"* - It's the easiest solution. The other options you would have are selecting every single image element and getting the last one, or simply getting the last child of the image container, both of which would take more effort to write.

Comment: Let more specify, I actually meant generally speaking how do you know when to use parameters?  Also, what do you reccomend for making this responsive?  It absolutely positioned

Comment: @NamelessDude21 Use percentages to make it responsive (e.g, `dogImgs.style.top = getRandomNum(100) + "%"`)

Comment: Another option is an image grid rather than a collage. Here's a responsive example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_grid_responsive